# Sort based on property values in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using the Sort feature provided in spring boot to sort my results. Consider an Entity "Employee" with properties like "id", "name" & "expertise".

"expertise" property can have values like "Java", "Python", "Admin", "Pascal" etc. I need to sort Employees based on expertise such that it is ordered as follows -

1. Python
2. Java
3. Pascal
4. Admin

Is there any way within the spring boot Sort feature to achieve such sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution. For each expertise, I added a column of type integer with name as "order_number". Instead of using the expertise name, I started using the order_number column for sorting and it produced the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using paging and sorting repository. Without that you will not be able to sort. For paging and sorting repository, you have to extend you repository method to PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>

Now, when you invoke findall() method, you can pass your sort parameter as well. Example-

```
List<Employee> employees = repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "expertise"));
```

Comment: The code provided by you will sort Employees based on expertise values in descending order. I am not looking for a descending/ascending order. I am looking for an order as provided in the post. For example, employees with Python expertise will come first, then employees with java expertise, and so on.

Comment: Got it. Then this will not work. Also, there is no library method available to do that. You have to write your custom code. And if there are too many records (in lakhs), performance may be compromised